# android not returning any data from mysql database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

i am currently working on a Android project that allows the user to Add/Update/Read and Delete records from a database. The application runs without any errors now but when i click on inserting a new record or viewing all employee records it returns nothing but a blank page? I don't think it can access the PHP files or could be anything else? I have a Config.java file with the addresses of my php files uploaded to my university mudfoot server and a ViewAllEmployee.java file that is called when the onClick is executed should return the results from my database using JSON. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to rectify this, i have been trying for the last few hours but cant seem to figure it out.

Config.java

```
package com.example.assignment.androidassignment;

public class Config {

//Address of our scripts of the CRUD
public static final String URL_ADD="http://www.mudfoot.doc.stu.mmu.ac.uk/students/abbasit/AndroidAssignment/addEmp.php";
public static final String URL_GET_ALL = "http://www.mudfoot.doc.stu.mmu.ac.uk/students/abbasit/AndroidAssignment//getAllEmp.php";
public static final String URL_GET_EMP = "http://mudfoot.doc.stu.mmu.ac.uk/students/abbasit/AndroidAssignment/getEmp.php?UserID=";
public static final String URL_UPDATE_EMP = "http://mudfoot.doc.stu.mmu.ac.uk/students/abbasit/AndroidAssignment/updateEmp.php";
public static final String URL_DELETE_EMP = "http://mudfoot.doc.stu.mmu.ac.uk/students/abbasit/AndroidAssignment/deleteEmp.php?UserID=";

//Keys that will be used to send the request to php scripts
public static final String KEY_EMP_ID = "UserID";
public static final String KEY_LAT = "Latitude";
public static final String KEY_LON = "Longitude";
public static final String KEY_TIMEINSERTED = "TimeInserted";

//JSON Tags
public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
public static final String TAG_ID = "UserID";
public static final String TAG_LAT = "Latitude";
public static final String TAG_LON = "Longitude";
public static final String TAG_TIMEINSERTED = "TimeInserted";

//employee id to pass with intent
public static final String EMP_ID = "UserID";
}
```

ViewAllEmployee.java

```
package com.example.assignment.assignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class ViewAllEmployee extends Activity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;

private String JSON_STRING;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all_employee);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getJSON();
}


private void showEmployee() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,  String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String UserID = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
            String Lat = jo.getString(Config.TAG_LAT);

            HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(Config.TAG_ID, UserID);
            employees.put(Config.TAG_LAT, Lat);
            list.add(employees);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            ViewAllEmployee.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_ID, Config.TAG_LAT},
            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getJSON() {
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(ViewAllEmployee.this, "Fetching Data", "Wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showEmployee();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewEmployee.class);
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap)  parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String UserID = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
    intent.putExtra(Config.EMP_ID, UserID);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
 }
```

dbConnect.php

```
<?php

define('HOST','XXXX');
define('USER','XXXX');
define('PASS','XXXX');
define('DB','XXXX');

//Connecting to Database
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

getAllEmp.php

```
<?php 
//Importing Database Script 
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Creating sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM locationtrace";

//getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//creating a blank array 
$result = array();

//looping through all the records fetched
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

    //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
    array_push($result,array(
        "UserID"=>$row['UserID'],
        "Latitude"=>$row['Latitude']
        "Longitude"=>$row['Longitude']
        "TimeInserted"=>$row['TimeInserted']

    ));
}

//Displaying the array in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: It seems that you have an extra slash in the `URL_GET_ALL` URL `//getAllEmp.php`

Comment: missing commas `"Latitude"=>$row['Latitude']
        "Longitude"=>$row['Longitude']`

Comment: I have tried a get for example with : URL_GET_ALL  and it doesn´t work. (Internal Server Error), are you sure that all the urls are working?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Fred-ii- i have added the commas but it still doesn't seem to work, when i run my URL in the browser it is returning ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. Would it be better if i created a live hosting server for now instead of using my University one?

Comment: The URL's were working before but now i have just realised they are not, Is there anywhere else you recommend uploading my php pages? like a live hosting server? @elenasys sorry i am quite new to this and have never used php with android before so not quite so on how i would set it up..